# Ho to connect to Power BI dataset using ADOMD.Net

Tags: c#, powerbi, adomd.net

I am using **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll**, v13.0.0.0 to to access a Power BI data set from C# code.
Have been experimenting with various connection strings but always get exceptions...

```
var connectionString = @"Provider=MSOLAP.7;Integrated Security=;Identity Provider=AAD;Data Source=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api;Initial Catalog=XXXX-XXXX-GUID;Location=https://wabi-us-north-central-redirect.analysis.windows.net/xmla?vs=sobe_wowvirtualserver&db=XXX-XXX-GUID;MDX Compatibility= 1; MDX Missing Member Mode= Error; Safety Options= 2; Update Isolation Level= 2;User ID=my@workemail.com;Password=my_pswd;";
var conn = new AdomdConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open(); //throws here
```

The connection string above produces error

> "The connection either timed out or was lost."

This string is based on the .odc file that I downloaded from Power BI, and it works fine from Excel - data is loaded into pivot table, etc. (Excel uses COM driver I guess?)

If I set Integrated `Security = SSPI` or `Basic`, the client throws another error saying that neither of them can be used with HTTP.

What is missing in my code? I am looking for a working sample of a connection string for Power BI. 
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
There is an inner exception for the connection string above:
"The remote name could not be resolved: 'analysis.windows.net'"
This url is what Power BI puts into odc file when I click on ANALYSE IN EXCEL. What url should I use to connect to data from .Net code?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that to connect to power bi i needed version 19.9.0 , connection will prompt for username and password.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64

```
connectionString= $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/{workspacename};";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the NuGet Package "[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64)" in my Project with the following Connectionstring:

```
Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/{WorkspaceName};Initial Catalog=Sales;User ID=app:{ApplicationId}@{TenantID};Password={Application Secret};
```

More Details [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/de-ch/blog/announcing-support-for-service-principals-using-the-xmla-endpoint-in-power-bi-premium/)